# Is it absolutely mandatory to replace ">" by "&gt;" in XML files?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

I have a simple XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Document>
 <DATEN>
  <DTA_Coding_Line>0100011509856>249099000000000000004039555+ 010001456></DTA_Coding_Line>
 </DATEN>
</Document>
```

I have validated this file with several online XML validation tools and it does not create errors.

Yet, in XML documentations I can read that I would have to escape the ">" character with `&gt;`.

- Is this mandatory at all?
- When would I have to replace `>` with `&gt;`?
- If the software reading this file above has issues with the `>` not being escaped, can it still be considered as "compliant" the XML standard?
- Is there such a "compliancy"?

Comment: The answer is that some xml parsers may choke on XML entities embedded within tags and attributes, which are reserved characters as part of the spec. Using CDATA sections will get around this as the spec stipulates it can hold anything in between the CDATA begin and end sequence, i.e. `<![CDATA[` `]]>`

Comment: Only require to replace if sending by HTML.  These are special characters for HTML and need to be replace if the xml is part of a html message.

Comment: For future reference, on Stack Overflow, you can format `&gt;` as code (via surrounding ` characters) so you don't need to add spaces.

Comment: Per the W3C XML Recommendation, and [**@spodger's answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51821100/290085) here (+1), > only need be escaped as `&gt;` as part of `]]>` when `]]>` is not ending a CDATA section. This is very rare (and is therefore marked as esoterica in my definitive [**Simplified XML Escaping**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46637835/290085) answer to [*What characters do I need to escape in XML documents?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1091945/290085)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

">" only needs to be escaped when used in the string "]]>" in content where the string "]]>" is not marking the end of a CDATA section.

On the other hand, "<" and "&" must always be escaped.

[Character Data and Markup](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#syntax)

which links to

> 2.4 Character Data and Markup
>
> Text consists of intermingled character data and markup. [Definition:
>   Markup takes the form of start-tags, end-tags, empty-element tags,
>   entity references, character references, comments, CDATA section
>   delimiters, document type declarations, processing instructions, XML
>   declarations, text declarations, and any white space that is at the
>   top level of the document entity (that is, outside the document
>   element and not inside any other markup).]
>
> [Definition: All text that is not markup constitutes the character
>   data of the document.]
>
> The ampersand character (&) and the left angle bracket (<) MUST NOT
>   appear in their literal form, except when used as markup delimiters,
>   or within a comment, a processing instruction, or a CDATA section. If
>   they are needed elsewhere, they MUST be escaped using either numeric
>   character references or the strings " & " and " < "
>   respectively. The right angle bracket (>) may be represented using the
>   string " > ", and MUST, for compatibility, be escaped using either
>   " > " or a character reference when it appears in the string " ]]>
>   " in content, when that string is not marking the end of a CDATA
>   section.
>
> In the content of elements, character data is any string of characters
>   which does not contain the start-delimiter of any markup and does not
>   include the CDATA-section-close delimiter, " ]]> ". In a CDATA
>   section, character data is any string of characters not including the
>   CDATA-section-close delimiter, " ]]> ".
>
> To allow attribute values to contain both single and double quotes,
>   the apostrophe or single-quote character (') may be represented as "
>   ' ", and the double-quote character (") as " " ".
>
> Character Data
>
> [14]    CharData    ::=    [^<&]* - ([^<&]* ']]>' [^<&]*)