# JAXB not transforming > symbol to &gt

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, jaxb

XML file generated using JAXB not translating ">" symbol to &gt. But it translating other XML escape characters such as <, & , ' , " . Is it by design or I need to use any specific library to transform all XML escape characters .

Comment: Related to [Is it absolutely mandatory to replace “>” by “&gt;” in XML files? {duplicate}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51816694/)

Comment: I am more looking towards why JAXB failed to translate ">" symbol , What parameters need to be changed to translate to &gt . One of our subsystem which reads the XML file failing because of ">" symbol in data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say "One of our subsystem which reads the XML file failing because of ">" symbol in data".

Then you need to fix that subsystem. Anything that reads XML should accept the full XML syntax; you can't expect the software that generates the XML to generate your particular favourite subset.

We see this a lot on StackOverflow. We see people generating XML badly, and then trying to repair it on the receiving end, and we see people parsing XML badly, and expecting to fix it on the sending end. When you do this, you've missed the whole point of XML, which is that it's a standard syntax that everyone can use; by adopting a standard syntax you can use standard tools for XML generation and XML parsing, which dramatically reduces your overall costs.

You're going to tell me that you have to fix it in the sender because you can't fix it in the receiver. Well, sorry: if you want a cowboy job you'll have to turn to someone else. If your electrical sockets are the wrong shape, I'm not going to help you bend the pins on your electrical plugs to make them fit, I'm going to tell you to replace the sockets.